# Is it possible to call a function in my SELECT statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have a database which holds different locations, each of which has its own longitude and latitude variable.  I want to be able to use a distance function I made that returns the distance between two longitudes and latitudes in my WHERE statement.  So I am looking for the distance between two points and it pass the WHERE statement if it is less than the radius I am searching.

distance function:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return $miles;
}
```

inside my SELECT statement I want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE distance($latitude, $longitude, 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

however that is not working.
I have tried these without any luck...

```
"SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE distance($latitude, $longitude, 'latitude', 'longitude') < $radius"
```

and

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE %f < $radius", distance($latitude, $longitude, 'latitude', 'longitude'))
```

Is this even possible to preform?  If not what is a good way around this problem?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I tried to do

```
"SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE '" . distance('Latitude', 'Longitude', $latitude, $longitude) . "' < $radius"
```

but it didn't work however if I just echo it it outputs the result I am looking for.  But it doesn't work right when I try to use it inside mysqli_query

Comment: your distance function needs to return a value witch you then add to the query

Comment: distance returns the distance between the two points.  Should i put the rest of the function on there?

Comment: i think this is just a pp string concatenation issue `$fooo='text'.my_function_output().'more text';` my_function_output() needs to return the string you want inside $foo

Comment: possible duplicate of [a php function inside a mysql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750891) (No, you can't. You could craft a stored procedure perhaps. Otherwise do a roundtrip. Note that SQLite can call back PHP functions easily, because it runs in the same process.)

Answer (score 1):

I have use this same but one issue:
I have used in query as follow:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql = "select ... AND '".distance2($lat,$long,'tbl_parkinglocations.lat',`tbl_parkinglocations.lat`) ."'<=20 ";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

but in function:

```
function distance2($lat1,$long1,$lat2,$long2){
            //Google api

            echo $fromAddress=$lat1.','.$long1;
            echo $toAddress=$lat2.','.$long2;
                // echo "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$fromAddress&destinations=$toAddress&sensor=false";
            $URL = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$fromAddress&destinations=$toAddress&sensor=false"));

            echo "<br>".$URL; exit;

            $status = $URL->rows[0]->elements[0]->status;
            if($status != 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
                    $res = round($URL->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value/1000);
                     return $res;
            }
        }
```

it gets 3rd and 4th param as follow:
3rd->tbl_parkinglocations.lat
4th->tbl_parkinglocations.lat

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to store your function's result in a variable and then you can add it into your select query.

Comment: But I need each locations longitude and latitude.  That way I only get the locations that are in the search radius.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE " . distance($latitude, $longitude, 'latitude', 'longitude') . " < $radius";
```

Comment: Still no luck.  Thanks though.

Comment: Yea just added the distance method

Comment: Use semicolon after return $miles `return $miles;`

Comment: The semicolon is there I just miss copied it.

Comment: When i run that string in an echo to see if it is making the right string it outputs right but when i try to do it inside my query it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that.

You could create a stored procedure that can calculate the distance of a location from the specified coordinate, and then use that stored procedure in your SQL query.

Or you could inline your distance calculation in the SQL query for example as shown [here in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372831/246622).

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to all this.  Which of these two options would probably be easier for a beginner to figure out.  Also what do you mean by 'inline' your distance calculation?

Comment: The easiest to do for a beginner would be the second alternative where you would create an SQL query similar to the one in the linked answer.

Comment: Oh gotcha.  So basically do the calculation and assign it with AS.  So in my php file where I do the SELECT statement can I use my variables liks &longitude and &latitude of will it be a problem because I pass it as a string to mysql_query

Comment: I used a version of the linked answer and I can now find the distance away all the locations are but how do I use this information to only pull the once that are within the radius.  I read somewhere that the calculation I did in SELECT to find 'distance_in_km' is not calculated until after WHERE is run, so I cannot say WHERE distance_in_km < $radius