# How do I UPDATE each column's row in MySQL using a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to port all passwords from one value to another value (each user), so I am looking for an applicable way to port all of them in MySQL, I am basically looking to run my crypt function over all `$row['password']`.

currently I have a `SELECT` and instead of doing a seperate `UPDATE` I was thinking how to do this in one connection.
I've written my `SELECT` so far and I have an array of my model.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_user";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$encryption_service = new EncryptionService;

$newUserSet = [];
foreach ($result as $row){
    $row['password'] = $encryption_service->encrypt($password);
    $newUserSet[] = $row;
}
```

How would I update all rows for password column in one query? I'm a bit confused on how to read a balue and then invoke a function on the value in an update statement.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: check the end of the OP, added more precise question.

Comment: Why do you make your own encrypt function? Did you try to use php's build in functions **password_hash** and **password_verify**??

Comment: Anyway, if your function is a php function you will need to retrieve all users data, recalculate the password and then do an update. There is no way you can execute a php function inside a mysql query

Comment: Read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750891/a-php-function-inside-a-mysql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a php function inside a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750891/a-php-function-inside-a-mysql-query)

Comment: @nacho can you show me a general execution for what you commented?